# Create an array of struct or object from json swift

Tags: json, swift, struct

I have a JSON filled with a list of Vendors. Whats the best and most efficient way of holding this as instances that are easily accessible within the class and passable through the project. I was thinking of using struct as i haven't used them before. Is it better than using Object?

Below i have my Struct.

```
struct Vendor {
let name: String
let latitude: Double
let longitude: Double

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
    self.latitude = dictionary["Lat"] as? Double ?? 0.0
    self.longitude = dictionary["Lng"] as? Double ?? 0.0
}
init?(data: Data) {
    guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
    self.init(dictionary: json)
}
init?(json: String) {
    self.init(data: Data(json.utf8))
}
```

}

My question is how would i create an Array from the JSON of this struct type.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using a `struct` is a great way to encapsulate your data. As long as the `struct` models your JSON accurately you can covert to and from JSON easily.

If you conform your `struct` to `Codable` then encoding and decoding to JSON is fairly simple:

```
import Foundation

// Conform to Codable
struct Vendor: Codable {
  let name: String
  let latitude: Double
  let longitude: Double
}

// create Array
var vendors = [Vendor]()
for i in 1...3 {
  let vendor = Vendor(name: "Foo", latitude: Double(i), longitude: 20.0)
  vendors.append(vendor)
}

// encode the Array into a JSON string
// convert to Data, then convert to String
if let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(vendors),
  let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
  print(jsonString)

  // [{"name":"Foo","longitude":20,"latitude":1},{"name":"Foo","longitude":20,"latitude":2},{"name":"Foo","longitude":20,"latitude":3}]

  // decode the JSON string back into an Array
  // convert to Data, then convert to [Vendor]
  if let vendorData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8),
    let vendorArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Vendor].self, from: vendorData) {
    print(vendorArray)

    // [__lldb_expr_8.Vendor(name: "Foo", latitude: 1.0, longitude: 20.0), __lldb_expr_8.Vendor(name: "Foo", latitude: 2.0, longitude: 20.0), __lldb_expr_8.Vendor(name: "Foo", latitude: 3.0, longitude: 20.0)]
  }
}
```